# Ember Data Relationships representations - create record not working

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a User and a Message model that look like this:

//models/user.js

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

//models/message.js

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  body: DS.attr('string'),
  sender: DS.belongsTo('user', { inverse: null }),
  receiver: DS.belongsTo('user', { inverse: null }),
  user: DS.belongsTo('user')
});
```

Here's how the messages/message route looks like:

//messages/message/route.js

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
model(params) {
  return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      messages: this.store.query('message', { filter: {user: params.user}   }),
      user: this.store.findRecord('user', params.user),
    });
  },

  setupController(controller, models) {
    controller.set('messages', models.messages);
    controller.set('user', models.user);
  }
});
```

and in the router.js I have

```
this.route('messages', function() {
  this.route('message', { path: ':user' });
});
```

So basically when you go to `/messages/{user_id}` you can view all the messages the current user has with the an user that has the {user_id}. Here's a JSON response I get from the server when visiting `messages/5`

```
{
"messages": [
  {
    "id": 10,
    "sender": 1,
    "receiver": 5,
    "body": "Hello world!",
    "user": 5
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "sender": 1,
    "receiver": 5,
    "body": "Sorry, I don't get it!",
    "user": 5
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "sender": 5,
    "receiver": 1,
    "body": "Is it possible?",
    "user": 5
  }
]
```

}

Now when trying to create a new message there's no sender, receiver or user ids to associate the new record created with, in order to send these over to the server.

Here's what I have in the payload

```
{
  "body":"New message",
  "sender":null,
  "receiver":null,
  "user":null
}
```

It's clear I'm doing something wrong with the relationships and not sure how to handle these.

//edit

Here's how I handle the message creation:

```
actions: {
    sendMessage() {
        const flashMessages = Ember.get(this, 'flashMessages');
        this.store.createRecord('message', {
            body: this.get('message'),
            sender: this.get('currentUser.id'),
            user: this.get('user.id'),
        }).save().then(() => {
            flashMessages.success('Message sent!', {
                timeout: 2000,
                destroyOnClick: true
            });
        });
    },
}
```

Comment: How you create a new message? Can you post the code for that?

Comment: I've just edited the OP to include the `sendMessage()` action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your message model, `sender`, `user`, and `receiver` are all relationships, so ember-data is expecting user objects. you are just giving it IDs in your `sendMessage` action.

I believe there are two ways to remedy this:

#1: use the IDs

#2: use the objects

example of #1:

```
actions: {
    sendMessage() {
        const flashMessages = Ember.get(this, 'flashMessages');
        this.store.createRecord('message', {
            body: this.get('message'),
            senderId: this.get('currentUser.id'),
            userId: this.get('user.id'),
        }).save().then(() => {
            flashMessages.success('Message sent!', {
                timeout: 2000,
                destroyOnClick: true
            });
        });
    },
}
```

example of #2:

```
actions: {
    sendMessage() {
        const flashMessages = Ember.get(this, 'flashMessages');
        this.store.createRecord('message', {
            body: this.get('message'),
            sender: this.get('currentUser'),
            user: this.get('user'),
        }).save().then(() => {
            flashMessages.success('Message sent!', {
                timeout: 2000,
                destroyOnClick: true
            });
        });
    },
}
```

One or both of those should get you out of your current jam.

Comment: Thanks Kori, using the example #2 did it :)